# Play2: How to do execute piece of code before each test using specs2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I have this code:

```
class AccountSpec extends Specification {


    def fakeApp = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())

    "Every account" should {

        "have a user" in running(fakeApp) {

            Account.create("Basic account", "username")
            ...
            etc...
        }
    }
}
```

If i try to run this spec I will get an error, because there is no user with a username "username". So what I would like to do is:

```
def before = { createTestUser() }
```

i have tried different approaches but havent found a solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just extend from this trait `org.specs2.mutable.BeforeAfter`, it comes with before and after methods, implement them, here is a link to documentation [docs](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-2.3.13/index.html#org.specs2.mutable.BeforeAfter)

Comment: Dead link, [here are the new docs](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-2.3.13/index.html#org.specs2.mutable.BeforeAfter).